# setApplicationIconBadgeNumber not having any effect

Tags: ios

I'm experimenting with clearing notifications from the notification center (where the workarounds include setting the badge number to 0, as there is no api to remove them).

However while experimenting I have noticed that I cannot get setApplicationIconBadgeNumber to have any effect on the badge number.

For example if I have:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 5];
```

(and setApplicationIconBadgeNumber is not being called anywhere else)

then there is no badge for the icon, let alone one containing a number.

(The notifications are not setting a badge number, perhaps there has to be a badge number to begin with before setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: has any effect, can anybody confirm or deny that?)

UPDATE:, I've noticed this in the console, maybe its related:

```
May 24 16:12:49 unknown installd[138] <Error>: entitlement 'aps-environment' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
May 24 16:12:49 unknown SpringBoard[51] <Warning>: Killing com.mycompany.xxx for termination assertion
May 24 16:12:50 unknown installd[138] <Error>: entitlement 'aps-environment' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
May 24 16:12:50 unknown SpringBoard[51] <Warning>: Reloading application state for 'com.mycompany.xxx' as its modification date or path has changed
May 24 16:12:50 unknown SpringBoard[51] <Warning>: Reloading and rendering all application icons.
```

The last line sounds relevant, this has only just started happening, no idea why, I haven't changed profiles etc. and they are up to date and valid in Xcode. I'll post a separate question for this

Comment: I'm not getting that in the console any more, but I still can't get any badge icon to appear. Doing my head in.

Answer (score 13):

If you're having trouble `setApplicationIconBadgeNumber` not working in iOS8+ it's because you have to ask the user permission for local notifications starting in iOS8:

```
UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge;
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

Comment: This is also needed in iOS 8.

Comment: @arlomedia: You're right. I updated my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You might try incrementing and decrementing the badge number one by one.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber++;
```

Although, I suspect your problem is more a matter of when your program gets to this line of code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem too.

Whilst testing it on your device, the line below is the correct call:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 5];`

Its where it gets called that matters though. If you only call it in:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

It will only execute if the application has fully closed. Whilst testing, because you are in and out of it a lot, the app may only enter the background and be paused, in which case call it in as well:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that it must be a number > 0. It didnt work any way with a negative number.